# linux prevent user read other directory

Tags: linux

I created a user which using the /bin/rbash, so it cannot execute some commands, like 'cd' and 'ls'. But it still can browser other directory when enter some path like '/bin/', then using tab the shell will show the files under 'bin'. And this user only allowed to login through serial port. How can I restrict the user only work in it's home dirctory, and not read other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search I have found this couple of questions that I think may fit your requirements

[Create ssh user which can only access home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124163/create-ssh-user-which-can-only-access-home-directory)

[Give user read/write access to only one directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101576)

Answer (score 0):

put

```
set disable-completion on
```

string in ~/.inputrc and restart your shell. it will disable completion at all.

this can solve my questions

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `chroot` to implement a user that does not see other directories.
This might be quite crazy solution, and not recommended way to do it.

Create a script that makes chroot

```
#!/bin/sh    
exec /usr/sbin/chroot /home/test /bin/sh
```

Use the script as login shell (/etc/passwd):

```
test:x:0:0:Linux User,,,:/:/usr/sbin/chrootsh.sh
```

Copy all needed files to home directory of the user. You need at least shell and libraries that are needed for the shell:

```
~ # ls -lR /home/test/
/home/test/:
total 2
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     test          1024 Aug 21 13:54 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     test          1024 Aug 21 13:54 lib

/home/test/bin:
total 1776
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     test        908672 Aug 21 13:54 ls
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     test        908672 Aug 21 13:54 sh

/home/test/lib:
total 1972
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     test        134316 Aug 21 13:54 ld-linux.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     test       1242640 Aug 21 13:54 libc.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     test        640480 Aug 21 13:54 libm.so.6
~ #
```

Ready. Then login as the user:

```
~ # su - test
/ # pwd
/
/ # ls -lR /
/:
total 2
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        1000          1024 Aug 21 13:54 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        1000          1024 Aug 21 13:54 lib

/bin:
total 1776
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        1000        908672 Aug 21 13:54 ls
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        1000        908672 Aug 21 13:54 sh

/lib:
total 1972
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        1000        134316 Aug 21 13:54 ld-linux.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        1000       1242640 Aug 21 13:54 libc.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        1000        640480 Aug 21 13:54 libm.so.6
/ #
```